# Connect laravel container to existing mysql container via docker compose

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I am new to docker, I am trying to connect the existing MySQL container to my Laravel application through docker-compose.

Where MySQL docker-compose.yml file is like

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_web
    build:
     context: ./docker/web
    ports:
      - "9000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/app
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_db
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel_docker_db
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       type: none
       device: /storage/docker/laravel_mysql_data
       o: bind
```

This script is downloading the latest mysql version and making a new container. I just want to connect MYSQL container with my application

Where my existing MYSQL container is created with a specific IP using a bridge network and running on docker-machine.

[image]

I am wondering, can I define the existing MYSQL container configurations on the **db context**?

Comment: Can you show us all your `docker-compose.yml` contents?

Comment: What's the specific problem you're encountering?  Have you read through [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation?

Comment: @MuhammadSipra Post your env too..I mean env for the DB_*..

Answer (score 3):

Try this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  db:
    container_name: myapp_db
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel_docker_db
    networks:
      - myapp-network

networks:
  myapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Situation has two cases:
1. If your laravel instance is in docker too - just add to .env file next rows:

```
DB_HOST=myapp_db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_docker_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

2.If you don't use docker for laravel - just change variable `DB_HOST=localhost`

Comment: the issue is still the same, 

I have the case 1: I am using laravel on docker. and the script created 2 containers 1st for laravel 2nd for mysql

Comment: Have you added `networks: - myapp-network` to your laravel container? docker connects containers in one network, and inside container you can call other container by name

Comment: also, if you use 1 option - change `DB_PORT=3306`

Comment: Yes , as per your answer i haeve added the networks in db context as well as I have also defined  networks:  myapp-network:     driver: bridge in it.

Comment: I think, if I have an MYSQL docker container that is already running on docker-machine, I just need to add the configuration in my laravel .env file. and remove MYSQL configs from the docker-compose.yml file. What do say?

Comment: no, environment in docker-compose file - it container build configuration. .env - just connection configs. Can you connect to your docker `docker exec -it myapp_db sh` to check if DB is exists: `mysql -uroot -proot laravel_docker_db` than: `show tables`

Comment: Docker Compose [creates a network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and you do not need any manual `networks:` settings for this to work.

Comment: @DavidMaze No, we need to manually set the networks if the app isn't inside the container. His explanation is correct afaik..

Answer (score 1):

In .env file:

```
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your database name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: `3007` is the published port. Since you're using `db` as host, then port should be `3006`.